# find and replace pattern in file in multiple files

Tags: regex, bash, awk, replace

I have 200 text files with the following structure:

```
n01443537_0.JPEG    0   10  63  58
...
n01443537_499.JPEG  0   3   39  42
```

In every file the first part (before the underscore i.e. **n01443537**) is different. However, they all have the same structure i.e start with *n*, followed by eight digits.

I would like to have all 200 files formatted as follows:

```
n01443537/n01443537_0.JPEG n01443537
...
n01443537/n01443537_499.JPEG n01443537
```

I found that this regex `n[^_]*` captures the required pattern, but having a little trouble putting it all together.

Comment: What are you doing with the rest of the info on each line? (e.g. `'    0   10  63  58'`)?

Comment: I just delete that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your files are in the current directory, you can use `sed` from the command line, something like this:

```
sed --in-place 's|\(^n[0-9]*\)\(_[0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)|\1/\1\2 \1|' *
```

This `|\1/\1\2 \1|` is your target, the first `\1` matches the first part (e.g. n01443537) then comes a `/` then again the `\1` then `\2` (e.g. _499.JPEG) then a space and finally `\1`

the `\[number]` refers to each group closed between parenthesis here `|\(^n[0-9]*\)\(_[0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)|`

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Not proficient in `awk` or `bash`.

The regex suitable for this case will be as follows.

**Regex:** `((n\d{8})_\d+\.JPEG).*`

**Replacement to do:** `\2/\1 \2`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vS9kI5/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks man, I just learnt that I can use nested groups, so the expression in my answer can be rewritten as: `sed 's|\(\(n[0-9]*\)_[0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\)|\2/\1 \2|' *`.

Comment: Take care white nesting. Group are numbered from outside to inside. Might confuse in cases like `( ( ( ) ( ) ) ( ) )`. Experiment and find out ;-)